# Do wands provoke attacks of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, opportunity-attack

In combat, are wands like ranged weapons and susceptible to attacks of opportunity?

And

Can you use the similar ranged feats to avoid attacks of opportunity, if not are there any?

Just **wand**ering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

- No, wands don't provoke opportunity attacks *like* ranged weapons do. Wands are **spell trigger items**, not ranged weapons, so they don't have anything to do with the rules for ranged weapons and opportunity attacks.
- No, wands don't provoke opportunity attacks, because [the definition of wand says so](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/wands.html#wands):

  > Wands use the spell trigger activation method, so casting a spell from a wand is usually a standard action that doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity.

As a result, no ranged-weapon feats for opportunity attacks are relevant to wands, and they don't need them to avoid provoking opportunity attacks anyway.

Comment: But if the spell cast by the wand requires a ranged touch attack, you still provoke from this ranged attack.

Comment: @ShadowKras Does it though? I'd always understood the rule to be specific to ranged *weapons*: only *aiming* an attack spell is called out as being like a ranged weapon, and it's a touch attack, and the entry for touch spells explicitly says they don't provoke. So like, casting a ray beside a enemy provokes one AoO because casting a spell does, but not two provokes from casting & ranged attack roll. And since the spell trigger method removes the adjacent-enemy provoke, there's no provokes left.

Comment: Casting a ray provokes two AOOs. [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qdc).

Comment: @topquark Aha! I've been doing it wrong. Thank you for the cite!